# Как в React и react-yandex-maps отмечать объект в списке при клике на него на карте?

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api

Застрял, реально застрял с такой проблемой. Есть станица «Контакты» на сайте. На странице — карта и список объектов (филиалов). Остальное элементы опустим для упрощения.

Что нужно: взять из API информацию о филиале, добавить в список под картой и поставить соответствующую метку на карте (в API есть даже координаты).

Также нужно при клике на метку на карте вывести отдельный блок-информацию (который почти повторяет блок-описание, но содержит дополнительные данные). Схематично для простоты восприятия (гео-метки сделал специально разные, это не важно):

[image: пример того, как это будет выглядеть]

Для карты используется react-yandex-maps. Реакт только учу, поэтому много туплю из-за свалившихся задач.

Вопросы такие:

1. Как одновременно выводить филиал и в списке в филиалов и добавлять гео-метку на карту?
2. Как при клике на гео-метку развернуть дополнительное описание и поменять иконку на карте (чтобы было видно, куда ткнули)? Вот так наглядно:

[image: пример того, что происходит по клику на гео-метку]

Как правильно это сделать? В одном компоненте? Передавать состояния? Я увы, плохо всё это понимаю, но стараюсь. Подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: Если не знаете полного решения, то, пожалуйста, подскажите, с чего начать?

Answer (score 1):

Задаете state

```
constructor(){
super();
this.state = {
    markers: [],
    activeMarker: null
}
```

Получаете данные из API.

```
let markersURL = "ссылка на нужное в api";
    fetch(markersURL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        this.setState({
            markers: response //тут все сохраняется в state
     })
});
```

Маркеры выводите любым удобным способом (присваиваем key):

1. Placemark
2. GeoObject

см примеры в папке https://github.com/gribnoysup/react-yandex-maps/tree/master/examples/src/sandbox
или https://gribnoysup.github.io/react-yandex-maps/#/sandbox/controls/listbox

В нужном месте выводите блоки с контактами - массив тот же со state

```
const contacts = this.state.markers.map((marker, index)=>{
    return (
        <div className="contact (activeMarker===marker.id)?'active':''">
            <p>{marker.title}</p>
            <p>{marker.phone}</p>
            //... и так далее
        </div>
    );
});
```

Вставляете в нужный блок, например

```
<div className="contacts">
    {contacts}
</div>
```

На клик по метке ловите id маркера (при создании можно его задать)
В функции меняете activeMarker на текущий.
В выводе информации контакта, добавьте проверки и выводите доп информацию.

Полное решение не предлагаю, думаю Вы сами справитесь или уже справились)